# details of signal bar in android

Tags: android

In android emulators' **GSM** signal bar has four division.  May i know how much of signal is denoted by each division.  In android signal level is between 0-31.  What is the criteria for filling all divisions in signal bar.  I already simulates signal level in my program, but it has 5 divisions.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Answer is in the question, isn't it?

Comment: i want each division of the signal bar represent how much amount of signal.

Comment: 31/5 or 31/4 I guess... Did you checked the DBM values to confirm?

Comment: i already done a signal level indicator with 5 divisions, but i give signal strength of 15(half of full signal), my signal level indicator shows half and android's full.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get your problem. A signal strength of 15 SHOULD display half the indicator... Please edit your question, and post images if possible.

Comment: i edited the question and please compare signal levels between my program and android

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14986/discussion-between-shkschneider-and-hare-krishna)

Comment: @casperOne Please explain reason for close question

Comment: @harekrishna What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signal strength values are between 0 and 31: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo.html#getRssi%28%29

If your Settings / About gives you 15 then you're application is right and the emulator's status bar is just lagging.

Android's emulator is far from perfect ^^

Answer (score -1):

I assume deviding the signal level to the number of divisions should give you a the signal level per division. Ex: 31/5.

Comment: Please watch the comments on the OP...

Comment: @shkschneider, it seems was posted almost in the same time. I wouldn't spend my time re-writing the things that were said once.